# Mpi4py does not run faster than serial code

Tags: python-2.7, networkx, igraph, mpi4py

When I try to calculate the betweenness of a graph with 10,000 nodes for a test. It seems that mpi parallel version is as fast as the serial version. And I really do not know where the problem is. Here is the MPI code:

```
from igraph import *
from pyunicorn import Network,mpi
import time
def master():
    ig = Graph.Lattice([100, 100], 1, False, False, True)
    bt = Network.FromIGraph(ig, silence_level=0).betweenness()
    mpi.info()

start=time.time()
mpi.run()
print "Time is %.4F seconds"% (time.time()-start)
```

Also, the serial code is below:

```
from igraph import *
from pyunicorn import Network
import time
ig = Graph.Lattice([100,100],1,False,False,True)
bt1=ig.betweenness(directed=False,cutoff=None)

start=time.time()
bt=Network.FromIGraph(ig,silence_level=0).betweenness()
end=time.time()
print "Time is %.4F seconds"% (end-start)
```

Comment: In general, I suggest trying 100, 1000, 10000, etc. nodes and graphing the relative speeds of the serial and parallel versions. This will allow you to compare whether or not the startup cost and other issues associated with parallel programming are having a significant impact on speed.

Comment: Are you sure that you have pyunicorn properly hooked into MPI? The docs for util.mpi state: "Uses mpi4py if available, otherwise processes calls sequentially in one process."